# How to populate OpenIddict Token custom class properties before it is saved to the database

Tags: openiddict

I want to customise `AuthToken` by adding a new column to the database. I've created a custom class with an additional property that inherits from `OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreToken<Guid, OAuthApplication, OAuthAuthorization>`.

I'm struggling to work out where I should/can populate this property so it gets saved to the database when a token request comes in and it creates a new row in the `Token` database table. Any help would be appreciated.